# When an `int` at max value and tested with with postfix ++, is code well-defined?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

> EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.  C11dr §3.4.3 3

`int` overflow is undefined behavior, but does that apply to the following which exists the loop, and does not use the the side effect of the now out-of-scope `i`?  In particular, does this *Postfix increment* spec help?

> ... The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand. ... §6.5.2.4 2

Compiles without warnings with well-enabled C11

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // Specified behavior when `i` has the value `INT_MAX`?
  for (int i = INT_MAX - 2; i++ < INT_MAX;) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
2147483646
2147483647
Done
```

Of course code can be re-written to avoid this quandary with the below.  Still, looking for confirmation concerning the above.  (I think it is UB.)  A similar issue exists with `INT_MIN` and `i--`.

```
  for (int i = INT_MAX - 2; i < INT_MAX;) {
    i++; 
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
```

---

```
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
'-std=c11' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' xx.o' '-o' 'xx.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -MMD xx.d -MF xx.d -MP -MT xx.o -dD -Dunix -idirafter   ... xx.c
```

Comment: I could be confused, but I dont think `i` ever actually overflows in either case, doesnt it stop when it is equal to INT_MAX

Comment: @Vality Yes, execuatble did stop when `i++` returned `INT_MAX` as shown in the sample output.  The question is if that is well defined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the scope `i`, the program has undefined behaviour in the evaluaton of `i++` when `i` is 2147483647 (assuming INT_MAX=2147483647 on your system).

Your example can be re-written as:

```
include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  // Specified behavior when `i` has the value `INT_MAX`?
  {
      int i = INT_MAX;
      i++;
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

The value computation of `i++` results in integer overflow irrespective of whether the computed value is used or if that object cease to exist right after the next sequence point; sequence point or storage duration of the object is irrelevant whether there's an undefined behaviour here.

Comment: Good point.  A closer code might be `while (1) { int i = INT_MAX; if (i++ == INT_MAX) break; }` as I am trying to understand how, if possible, the `i++` is dividable. The result is sequenced before the increment per spec.  I guess the question may be if the `if(_test_the return_value_)` is an escape from the pending `++` UB - apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

The code has undefined behavior. The expression `i++` causes evaluation of `i+1` and assignment of the result to `i`, and the evaluation of `i+1` has undefined behavior. It doesn't matter that you don't use the result of `i+1` or the newly stored value of `i`. UB is not a matter of using the result. Likewise, `0*(INT_MAX+1)` has UB.

Comment: Agree about the `0*(INT_MAX+1)` is UB - but there is no sequencing/scope issues in that example.  Here `i++` has a _side-effect_ and is sequenced after the result.  It is that attribute that I am wondering about.

Comment: I don't see how you think the sequencing of the UB is relevant to whether there's UB. The text you quoted about sequencing is relevant in cases where the result is defined; it has no meaning in cases where the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: `i < INT_MAX && i++` is a certain case where sequencing prevents UB.  Just trying to discern how tied side-effects are coupled to sequencing.

Comment: @chux: No. Sequencing has nothing to do with that. Rather, the fact that the right-hand-side of `&&` is **not evaluated** if the left-hand-side is false is what prevents the UB. If you changed it to `i <= INT_MAX && i++` it would still be sequenced but the RHS would be evaluated and it would have UB.